# How do I plot species number (specnumber()-function) with vegan package?

Tags: r, plot, na, vegan

I have two dataframes, constructed as following:

`env <- read.csv("ud_area.csv", header = T, sep = ";", row.names = 1)`

`com <- read.csv("com_1.csv", header = T, sep = ";", row.names = 1)`

which are structured as follows:

```
str(env)

**data.frame':  4 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Area: chr  "BeetleBank" "BeetleBank" "Klee" "Klee"**

str(com)

**'data.frame': 4 obs. of  121 variables:**

**$ MT.1  : int  0 57 0 0**
 
**$ MT.2  : int  0 1 0 3**
 
**$ MT.3  : int  0 26 0 0** and so on...
```

Then I want to call and plot the specnumber()-function included in the vegan package:

`S<-specnumber(com)`

`plot(S ~ env$Area, ylab = "y", xlab = "x", ylim=c(0, 20), xlim=c(0,100))`

I always get the following error: NAs introduced by coercion.

I controlled the data multiple times for NAs, and it does not make sense to me. Additionally, when I run the script with other data a few months ago, I had no problems. Now, it also does not work with the old data. How is this possible?

Comment: In lack of information I resort to guessing: if you had a warning message (that you do not show), you probably had non-numeric data in your data.frame. If you didn't have a warning, you probably had `NA` values that were propagated to `NA` number of species. If you have non-numeric data, `sum(com)` will give an error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Area should be a factor in

```
plot(S ~ env$Area, ylab = "y", xlab = "x", ylim=c(0, 20), xlim=c(0,100))
```

but it is a character string. The following should work

```
plot(S ~ as.factor(env$Area), ylab = "y", xlab = "x", ylim=c(0, 20), xlim=c(0,100))
```

This is an incomprehensible change in **R** 4 that causes a lot of pain: earlier **R** automatically cast character strings to factors, but since version 4 it leaves them as character strings, and many statistical functions do not know what to do with them.

To keep the pre-4 behaviour in **R** you should read the data with command:

```
env <- read.csv("ud_area.csv", header = T, sep = ";", row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```